# Apache2: installing a module

Tags: apache-2.2, configuration

I'm trying to install mod_xsendfile.

I did:

```
apxs2 -cia mod_xsendfile.c
```

Error:

```
apxs:Error: Activation failed for custom /etc/apache2/httpd.conf file.. 
apxs:Error: At least one `LoadModule' directive already has to exist..
```

The file /etc/apache2/httpd.conf is empty. However, there are lots of module configs inside /etc/apache2/mods-available and mods-enabled/.

Do I have to add a dummy element to httpd.conf? Or is there a different solution?

Comment: Try to execute "find /etc/apache2/mods-available/ -type f -name '*' | xargs grep -l "LoadModule" | grep -i xsendfile"  What type of OS/Distro are you using?

Comment: I'm on Ubuntu (9.something).

Comment: @ALex_hha: Result: nothing.

Comment: Inside the mods-enabled and mods-available, can I just create one (.load) by hand for the xsendfile module? The .so file got previously installed.

Comment: Yes, you can. Also you could try to use https://launchpad.net/~davewalker/+archive/libapache2-mod-xsendfile

Comment: I've now done it the manual way and it worked. I can't upvote anything from you, so ... just thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer through comments with ALex_hha:

Create a /etc/apache2/mods-available/xsendfile.load file, content:

```
LoadModule xsendfile_module /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_xsendfile.so
```

and create a symbolic link in /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/xsendfile.load.

Do necessary changes specific for this module and restart apache2.

Answer (score 0):

Is there anything in apache2.conf?

You need to tell it to include the files in mods-enabled.

Something like:

```
# Include module configuration:
Include mods-enabled/*.load
Include mods-enabled/*.conf
```

Comment: The settings were already available.